# php file with php code converted to html comments

Tags: php

So I installed and setup apache and php I have a very basic hello world file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo 'HELLO';?>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked online they said to make sure that the file is php and not html. So yeah my file is indeed 'test.php' however when I run it and inspect it this is the html code.

[INSPECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOwJx.png)

so.. what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
Okay so I checked online and I have to a2enmod php however when I typed in a2enmod then tab to autocomplete I don't have a php option. So when I do run a2enmod php I get ERROR:Module php does not exist.

However when I do php -v I get this

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2022 13:29:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

So I guess php is correctly installed but it somehow isn't an option for a2endmod. what do?

EDIT 2:
So I ran this command
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4
after I did that when I open my website I get this error now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p10YF.png)

EDIT 3: So after installing the libapache2 thing I just did a2enmod php7.4 and that fixed it finally

Comment: How are you accessing it?

Comment: Make sure your PHP file is placed on a server capable of interpreting PHP properly. You said that you had installed apache and php in a server, but you also need to make sure that the configuration (e.g. httpd.conf) is set properly so that the server will parse/run a .php file thru the php handler

Comment: @KenLee I setup the conf file as shown at minute 20 of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrLAx27Npns&list=WL&index=84

However the file isn't name httpd.conf could that be it? Because I can't find a file called httpd.conf.

Comment: @KenLee edited original post

Comment: Great to know that you have fixed it finally. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If the file is being saved with a .php extension, like index.php, then the next step is to figure out why it's not sending .php files to the PHP engine. You would need to ensure that the PHP engine is indeed installed and Apache is properly configured to hand off .php files to PHP's Apache plugin (there are more advanced ways, but the plugin is the most basic/common way). The PHP documentation describes how to configure Apache (and other web servers) to use PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php